# why npm doesn't install angular/dev-kit

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, npm

hi while i am using npm to install dependencies at the end i got this error:
[image: ,]

and also i can not serve ionic because of a despondency 
[image]

here is the part of  log

```
17252 verbose optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
17252 verbose optional The operation was rejected by your operating system.
17252 verbose optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
17252 verbose optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: or that you lack permissions to access it.
17252 verbose optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
17252 verbose optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
17252 verbose optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
17252 verbose optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: the command again as root/Administrator.
17253 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'F:\ionic\itosoft\amnasnad-lts\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\parse5' -> 'F:\ionic\itosoft\amnasnad-lts\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\.parse5.DELETE'
17254 verbose cwd F:\ionic\itosoft\amnasnad-lts
17255 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
17256 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
17257 verbose node v12.16.1
17258 verbose npm  v6.13.4
17259 error code ENOENT
17260 error syscall rename
17261 error path F:\ionic\itosoft\amnasnad-lts\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\parse5
17262 error dest F:\ionic\itosoft\amnasnad-lts\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\.parse5.DELETE
17263 error errno -4058
17264 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'F:\ionic\itosoft\amnasnad-lts\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\parse5' -> 'F:\ionic\itosoft\amnasnad-lts\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\.parse5.DELETE'
17265 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
17266 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

full log at
https://gofile.io/?c=dKTtf3

Comment: i checked c drive too:
https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/ionicframework/original/3X/b/7/b79732e1d6deb3efc993d8c303133b8e4600fc38.png

Comment: also i ran as admin but this error:
run as admin
https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/ionicframework/original/3X/1/f/1f07a78591d486780dbc0a7ba66636551e9eb57a.png